SSIS failure with Error about Microsoft.ODBCSrc
Trying to run an SSIS package, that uses ODBC to connect to Teradata, deployed on the server and it throws the following error:
The managed pipeline component "Microsoft.SSISODBCSrc" could not be loaded.  The exception was: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SSISODBCSrc' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
It looks to me as if either a component hasn't been installed or it doesn't know where to find it.
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Tried ODBC connection which works on the laptop but fails on the server.

I found that for the project, the deployment set back several versions because the server hadn't been updated.


Going with the obvious first, has the Teradata Tools and Utilities been installed on the target machine? https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-tools-and-utilities-13-10
After that, configure however it's needed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/teradata-source?view=sql-server-ver16

I wish I could get all the downloads done with the company but red tape is a problem. I did find the solution in the SSIS project deployment target server had to be changed to several versions earlier.
